# Ranger Share Spells Ability with Animal Companion

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions

> Share spells: Beginning at 15th level, when you cast a spell targeting yourself, you can also affect your beast companion with the spell if the beast is within 30 feet of you.

Does "Share Spells" work if you have a spell such as cure wounds and target yourself with it, or even if you were to target yourself with something more ridiculous such as True Polymorph?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that's what it says and that's what it does. If it didn't, it would have no effect at all.